# Create Section with Video Background That Fills Initial Viewport and Allows Content to Fall Below It

Tags: css

To put it simply, I'm trying to create a div/section with a video background that fills the fullscreen of the initial viewport and allows other sections to follow it.

Something pretty much exactly like this: http://jmd.im/

Notice how no matter what your window size is, that section is always the size of your window, and remains like that until you scroll down. I'd like to have other sections below it, so that you may scroll down and view them.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Simply put the `<video>` tag in your section and give it a `position: absolute` and `z-index: -1` to let it fall behind all the other content in that section. Give the section a height of `100vh` and width of `100vw`. Depending on the size of the video, give it `object-fit: cover`. That should work as you wish :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a section and give it the viewport height, while adding a video into it that scales to fit:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
img, video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" />
</header>
```

Use the absolute positioning to push it to the back and just add your other content in.

Answer (score 0):

I gave the same answer as a comment, I thought I try it out and share the code to make it easier:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

/*.one { background: #DEBD63; }*/

.two {
  background: #DE6363;
}

.three {
  background: #6380DE;
}
```

```html
<section class="one">
  <video autoplay="true">
  <source src="https://ak2.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/2529842/preview/stock-footage-hd-flying-through-a-glorious-nebula-and-star-fields-in-deep-space-loop-formats-available.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>

  <div>
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="two"></section>

<section class="three"></section>
```